# Firebase data not sent to server until app restart on IOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using `childChanged`, `childAdded` and `childRemoved` observers on my views in a `swift` app. For some reason the data will not update across devices until the app that made the change restarts. Any ideas on what may cause this. I never had this issue, when I just watched the value on my observers.

```
        orderRef.keepSynced(true)
        orderRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot -> Void in
            self.orders = self.orders.filter({$0.key != snapshot.key})
            self.orders.append(snapshot)

            self.loadDispatch()
        })

        orderRef.observe(.childChanged, with: { snapshot -> Void in
            self.orders = self.orders.filter({$0.key != snapshot.key})
            self.orders.append(snapshot)

            if let value = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "settled").value as? Bool {
                if !value {
                    self.loadDispatch()
                }
            }
        })

        orderRef.observe(.childRemoved, with: { snapshot -> Void in
            self.orders = self.orders.filter({$0.key != snapshot.key})
            self.loadDispatch()
        })
```

Comment: Enable background modes in capabilities and run you above method in background operation

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to a call to removeAllObservers in another view controller. removeAllObservers removed all observers within the app not just the reference you called upon. Using a handle gives desired functionality.